# ortho-bromoanisole + NaNH2 + Liquid NH3 =?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

when we add ortho-bromoanisole in NaNH2 + NH3 we form products using the benzyne mechanism.[image: mechanism from my textbook]

here, we form the products considering only -I effect of -OCH3, if we consider its +M effect we would form, o-Anisidine, why is +M effect ignored here? is it because of sp2 hybridization of carbanion, if so, how?

Comment: Is the anion electron pair in conjugation with the lone pairs on the oxygen atom?

Answer (score 0):

First of all,you need to know the basics of Resonance. It is the transfer of π electrons between p orbitals parallel to each other. If they are not parallel,then there will be two cases:-

1)if atleast one of the p-orbital is free to rotate (generally in sp³ atom),then it will align its p-orbital parallel to it,then it's π electrons participate in Resonance.

2)In the second case, if the atom is not free to rotate (generally in sp² atom) then resonance do not happen.

Your Phenyl carbanion lies in the second case.The negative charge resides in the sp² hybrid orbital which lies in the plane of ring. But the resonance is happening in the p-orbitals  perpendicular to the plane of benzene ring. Therefore there is an angle of 90° between the orbital containing negative charge and other p-orbital participating in resonance. Also that carbon is not free to rotate.

Thus,there is no effect on reaction intermediate of Benzyne mechanism due to (+M)-effect. So Inductive effect is the deciding factor for the stability of phenyl anion.